ChartJS: Property 'fit' does not exist on type 'LegendElement<"bar">'
Quick question:
I'm using ChartJS with react-chart-js2 and typescript.
I wanted to increase padding between legend and chart, and got to a solution that works, but I can't seem to get the types right.
The solution: add the following code to plugins prop in JSX, or to ChartJS register method.
In both situations I get error:

Property 'fit' does not exist on type 'LegendElement<"bar">'.

(this appears when I hover over the .fit in the below code)
The code:
            plugins={[
              {
                id: "customSpacingLegend",
                beforeInit(chart) {
                  const originalFit = chart?.legend?.fit;

                  // Override the fit function
                  chart?.legend.fit = function fit() {
                    originalFit.bind(chart.legend)();
                    this?.height += 50;
                  };
                },
              },
            ]}

does anybody know maybe what's this about? the code works, but the types seem to not work, I don't know why, the TypeScript seems to justifiably complain about fit not existing, as it is not in the LegendElement spec https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/interfaces/LegendElement.html, but then again why does this work? Is the type of chart.legend actually different then the suggested LegendElement?

It will be fixed if you update to 4.4, which includes the latest and adds a type for the fit() method
Chart.js Type Definitions.
